# Attach arbitrary data to a XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to use one callback for many different XHR objects, however I also want to know what made the XHR call when it sends a message via onload/onerror/onprogress.
That is, assuming I get some message through either of the callbacks, I want the message to contain a member that I assigned when making the request.
Logically, I could simply set a field in the XHR object, and then use the target member of the event that points to the original XHR object...except my member is gone.
Nothing that I set manually stays set in the target member of the event.

The only other way I can think of is to keep binding new copies of the callbacks, e.g. onload.bind(whatever), but that is really not optimal.

So, long story short, is there a way to attach data to a XHR request, so it can later on be identified?

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I meant. Did you not read what I wrote, or did I write it in an obscure manner and should clarify?